Multi-Party computation or Secret Sharing libraries in Rust or NodeJS?
recently I've been trying to learn about Multi-Parti Computation and Secret Sharing. I read some high level articles about these concepts, and I wanted to try to write some small rust (or NodeJS) programs to see how they work. But I can't find any mature high-level libraries to that could help me. There are low-level cryptography libraries, but those would require me to implement the protocols manually. So are there any high-level libraries that you have used?
